# googlemap-like drag and zoom

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do you develop googlemap-like draggable effects on a set of divs? Are there javascript libraries to simulate that effect?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something that will allow you to pan and zoom.

Check out this plugin, it should do the trick for you.

http://www.netzgesta.de/shiftzoom/

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the link, however this seems not to have an endless pan to the div. I would appreciate to know of plugin or method to create an endless pan/scroll

Answer (score 0):

There is opensource javascript library for tiled maps: http://openlayers.org/